# Good pattern/practice for instrumenting asynchronous distributed processes to reconstruct process later?

Tags: logging, asynchronous, hierarchy, trace

Briefly: I'm looking for the best way to have distributed business processes emit trace info that lets me reconstruct a multi-app, asynchronous process while keeping the hierarchy and business order of that process intact, without requiring the consumer of this data to have deep knowledge of the process, or each app to have any knowledge that they're part of a bigger process.

We have several business processes that run asynchronously across several distributed apps. We want to have each app emit app trace/logging data in a standard format that will allow any given instance of any of these processes to be reconstructed in the correct order, even when some parts of these processes are asynchronous and/or occur in parallel, by a client with access to the raw data but no smarts around the actual steps in the process, which of course will change over time.

We already have a service bus type app that can collect and forward this data. I'm just trying to determine a good way to breadcrumb these events to put all the pieces back together in the correct order.

So for example, let's say this is Process #1

- App 1 - calls app 2
- App 2 - calls app 3 **asynchronously**, then immediately calls app 5

  - App 3 - calls app 4

    - App 4 - takes a really long time, so it finishes last
- App 5 - I'm last!

So if each app emitted an event with its app number, simply ordering those events by timestamp or sequence ID might show the steps as

- 1
- 2
- 5
- 3
- 4

This loses the hierarchy and makes it appear that 5 comes earlier in the process than 4, which is true on the clock, but wrong to the business. What I really want is a trace that looks like this:

- 1
- 2

  - 3

    - 4
- 5

Additional requirements:

1. Consumers of this data must not know that that's the trace outline they're trying to reconstruct. They should be able to build that trace themselves, including hierarchy, just from the data, say from a session ID that's shared across all the trace steps. If App 3 starts making calls to App 3A, only App 3 should need to know about this change. Everyone else should just see it in the data. **The consumer of this data must be kept loosely coupled from the details of the process it's looking at.**
2. App 3 may be part of 13 different processes. It cannot assume its steps are children of App 2's. It should just add to the hierarchy it is handed, or create a new one if none is given to it. **Each app must not know anything about the other apps**

I think I have a workable solution, but wanted to get feedback and/or see if this is a solved problem I'm missing. My idea is to have each of these apps take a new optional "X-Trace-Hierarchy" header (they're all custom web apps, and almost all RESTful) representing dot-delimited list of integers, as in an outline. If an app receives this header, it appends its own hierarchy to it as it does its job, including calling child apps. Steps within the app are added to the hierarchy as siblings, incrementing by 1 each time, and calls to outside services are added as children. As a result, the incoming `X-Trace-Hierarchy` header for the process above looks like this:

- App 1 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: (not sent, will default to 1)`
- App 2 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: 2`

  - App 3 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: 2.1`

    - App 4 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: 2.1.1`
- App 5 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: 3`

Now if I get a pile of trace steps for a given session, I can unambiguously reconstruct the **logical** order, regardless of the actual time sequence they occur, and without having any expectation or knowledge about what that order should be. In fact, a call to App 3 that's not part of this process will produce:

- App 3 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: (not sent, will default to 1)`

  - App 4 - `X-Trace-Hierarchy: 1.1`

so the hierarchy produced each time will always flow from the particular steps taken by that instance of the process, and might be different every time, but it will allow a relatively "dumb" client to reconstruct any arbitrary process from this data.

Yes, this requires each app to be updated to use `X-Trace-Hierarchy`, and it presumes guaranteed delivery of the emitted events, but I'm fine with that. Otherwise I can't think of problems with this approach, nor a better way to do it. But if you can, internet, please let me know.